# Check current page from controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Is there a way to check the current page from the controller? I tried

```
current_page?
```

but that returns an error :

```
undefined method 'current_page?'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the controller action and view the following helpers are available:

```
controller_name
action_name
```

You can guess from its' names, what each does.

Comment: Like the current_page? helper, neither of these work in the controller although they do in the view

Comment: Ahh my bad, `controller_name` and `action_name` work fine from the controller level too; I dunno what I did wrong previously. I found a more flexible way to find the current url from the controller though, using `request.path`. Thanks for showing me the right direction!

Answer (score 4):

try to check like this in view

```
logger.info("--------#{params[:controller]}-------------")

logger.info("--------#{params[:action]}-------------")
```

see in log of terminal